# How to insert multiple images into a blog post not File field upload (Django blog)

Tags: python, django, django-templates, blogs, filefield

I am a semi-noob to Django web development. I've managed to add a File field that actually allows me to upload an image into the post (The image is displayed in post-list and post-detail) but what if I wanted to add several images in a post?

I am currently writing a tutorial post and would like to insert images under each instruction for the benefit of the user. I don't want the tutorials to be purely text, how do I go about doing this?

Below is my models.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.utils import timezone
#from taggit.managers import TaggableManager


class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True)

    #tags = TaggableManager()

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def approved_comments(self):
        return self.comments.filter(approved_comment=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-pk"]

class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey('blog.Post', related_name='comments')
    author = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    approved_comment = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def approve(self):
        self.approved_comment = True
        self.save()

    def approved_comments(self):
        return self.comments.filter(approved_comment=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

And here's my forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Post, Comment

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Post
    fields = ('image','title', 'text')

class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('author', 'text',)
```

Here's a screen shot of my blog post, as you can see it's just posting the link when I include the HTML file

[My blog post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1l8f.png)

And finally below is a snippet of the post detail;

```html
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
&nbsp;

  {% if user.is_authenticated %}
       <a class="btn btn-default pull-left" href="{% url 'post_edit' pk=post.pk %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>
  {% endif %}

  <div id="post_det">
   {% if post.published_date %}
    <div class="date">
     {{ post.published_date }}
    </div>
   {% endif %}

   <h1 class="post-title">{{ post.title }}</h1>
    <img src="{{post.image.url}}" class="img-responsive blog-img"/>
    &nbsp; 
    
   <p class="post_text">{{ post.text|linebreaksbr }}</p>
   
   
  </div>
 &nbsp; 
 
 <hr>
  <a class="btn comment_button" href="{% url 'add_comment_to_post' pk=post.pk %}">Add comment</a>
  
 
 <div>
 &nbsp;  
 
  {% for comment in post.comments.all %}
  {% if user.is_authenticated or comment.approved_comment %}
   <div class="comment">
   <div class="date">
            {{ comment.created_date }}
            {% if not comment.approved_comment %}
                <a class="btn btn-default" href="{% url 'comment_remove' pk=comment.pk %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
                <a class="btn btn-default" href="{% url 'comment_approve' pk=comment.pk %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></a>
            {% endif %}
   </div>
   <strong>{{ comment.author }}</strong>
   <p>{{ comment.text|linebreaks }}</p>
   </div>
  {% endif %}
   {% empty %}
    <p>No comments here yet :(</p>
   {% endfor %}
 </div>
{% endblock %}
```

This seems like such a menial task and I am struggling to insert a simple image under some text. Can anybody help? Will greatly appreciate it.

Thank you

Sam

Comment: so, your problem is that you want to add multiple images? or that the image is not rendering correctly?

Comment: @alfonso.kim  I want to insert multiple images in a blog post. Right now I only know how to upload one and make it appear at the top of the post, as can be seen from my post detail snippet <img src="{{post.image.url}}" class="img-responsive blog-img"/> Do I need to edit the models.py file? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could add the images manually in the text field as html like `<img src="#">`. Then in the template use the "safe" filter. So `post.text|safe`. That will render your html.

But that only solves a part of your problem, because you need an easy way of uploading images to the server and inserting them into blog posts.

What you really need is a WYSIWYG editor. Here's a list https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/wysiwyg/

Django-ckeditor and tinymce are both pretty good. You can find tutorials for how to set those up in their respective docs.

Comment: Good to hear that my answer helped Curly77, could you give me an upvote and mark the answer as solving your problem?

Comment: I've marked the answer and upvoted, you can't see the upvote as I am new to stackoverflow. Thanks again!